# Making a function to be called within Linq functions

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework

Can I make a function to be called within Linq functions using EF?

for example

```
int GetEmployeeStatus(string empID)
{
     using (DB = new db())
     {
           var status = db.EmployeeStatus
                        .Where(e => e.EmpID == empID && e.StatusEndDate == null)
                        .Select(e => e.Status)
                        .SingleOrDefault();
           return status;
     }
}
```

Now is there a way to use the function above anywhere in my applciation in some way like this:

```
    ....
    var empList = db.Employees
                  .Where(e => e.CostCenterID == 123 
                         && GetEmployeeStatus(e.EmpID) == 1);
    ....
```

I do not want to write the creteria for finding the employee status over and over again, is there  a way to do that or something similar in concept?

One more thing, I know the way I write the function up will cause a database trip for every row, I hope there is way to avoid that and just to embed the query within the Linq so it will be called once.

Comment: Hope this link helps you. Do let me know.
http://tomasp.net/blog/linq-expand.aspx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use an extension function:

```
public static class DbContextExtensions 
{
    public static IQueryable<Employee> WhereX(this IQueryable<Employee> queryable, int id)
    {
        return queryable.Where(e => e.CostCenterID == 123);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1, based on his requirement I think you would want to return bool or int though.

Comment: Nice, will the SQL generated in this function be embedded into the SQL generated from the calling linq expression? in other means one trip to the Database?

Comment: @HaLaBi I highly suggest that you inspect the log of the data context to see for yourself.  If you do it properly, yes, it will be one single round trip, but if you don't do it properly, no.  Always get in the habit of checking that log file when developing new queries (especially when first working with a new a query provider) as it helps teach you a lot about how to write effective queries.

Comment: It does not matter if you use an extension function or have the where clause directly on the db context. You can even combine several extension functions. But nevertheless, as @Servy said always ceck if your queries are sent correctly to the database (using extension methods or not).

Comment: You suggest looking into `DataContext.Log`? Most of even good developers cannot judge what is good SQL and what will perform bad.

Comment: @MareInfinitus True, but it's usually pretty easy to see if you're doing one round trip to the DB or two.  It's also pretty easy to see if there is a query that looks more or less like it's getting the data you want or if it's just returning the whole table and doing everything via linq-to-objects.  Both are common errors that are easy to check for.

Comment: @MareInfinitus I would suggest using [EF Prof](http://www.hibernatingrhinos.com/products/efprof). Every dev should have it when working with EF.